# log4net separate file per api call

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I am working on a project which consists of two components. One is an ASP.NET Web API and the other one is a class library.

I have used log4net in the class library so that when I use the library I can get the messages logged inside.

What I am trying to accomplish is that every time a function inside one of the controllers is executed, I want to create a new log file that contains only the log messages generated inside this function call and the ones resulting from the call to the library.

What happens is that when I call the API twice at the same time messages from both calls are written to both files.

I use the following helper class to avoid use of configuration XML files:

```
public class Logger
{
    public static void ConfigureFileAppender(string logFile)
    {
        var fileAppender = GetFileAppender(logFile);
        BasicConfigurator.Configure(fileAppender);
        //((Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root.Level = Level.Debug;
    }

    private static IAppender GetFileAppender(string logFile)
    {
        var layout = new PatternLayout("%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline");
        layout.ActivateOptions(); // According to the docs this must be called as soon as any properties have been changed.

        var appender = new FileAppender
        {
            File = logFile,
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            Threshold = Level.All,
            Layout = layout
        };

        appender.ActivateOptions();

        return appender;
    }
}
```

Part of my API code:

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]ApiParameter parameter)
{
    var instanceId = $"{parameter.ActionInstanceId}_{parameter.ConfigFileName}_{DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy_HHmmss")}";

    string RunPath = Path.Combine(ROOT_PATH, instanceId);
    Logger.ConfigureFileAppender(Path.Combine(RunPath) +"\\ETLLOG.log");


    Log.Info("ETL API Started");

    ....
    ....
}
```

Comment: show the code you're using

Comment: edited post to add some code

Comment: From your code it looks like the path of the log file is generated at runtime using instanceid and datetime.now and configfilename. The final log file name is ETLLog.log. So as per your code it should create a different folder for every api call and create a log file ETLLog.log file over there. Is that not happening?  Or it is happening but you want something else?

Comment: As you have explained a new folder is created per call with a new log file in it. However the log messages for call A abd call B are written to both files. What I want is that log messages from calls A and B to only go their respective files.

Comment: Logic wise it looks to me is it keeps adding new file appenders to the log4net config which makes it writing in old and new log files. You can try removing all the previous file appenders before you configure a new file appender.